# node js when should I use a-sync mechanism

Tags: javascript, node.js

when I develop JS with UI integration I've used a-sync mechanism (like promises...) and now I've started to develop node js application and my question is when should I use async in which kind of process or code I should consider to use async in node...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use async with Node.js. The only exception is if you are doing something one-off like a build script. But if your code involves connections to users, there is never a reason to use sync function calls.

The reason is that Node is, fundamentally, a single-process HTTP server. If we used synchronous IO with Node, then if we needed to read from a DB connection, only one HTTP request would be able to do this at a time. It is not good to have an HTTP server than only serve one user at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You should do async whenever there is I/O over network or I/O with fileSystem.

Now here over Network means when you are connecting to databases over network or on localhost or you are trying to connect to another server and fileSystem means when you are trying to read file from disk or trying to write file on disk.

Thanks.